# Detecting source of exception in CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java, completable-future

In the following example code, I want to know how to *properly* detect the source of the exception since depending on where the exception originated from, different logic should be executed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    cf
      .exceptionally(ex -> {
        throw (RuntimeException) ex; // rethrow because we want to interrupt the subsequent logic
      })
      .thenAcceptAsync((unused) -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("oops");
      })
      .whenComplete((unused, ex) -> {
         System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName()); // --> CompletionException
         // which runtime exception (ex) is in here, 'first' or 'second'?
         // depending on the exception, different logic should run
       });

    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
      cf.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException("oops"));
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you do `throw (RuntimeException) ex;` in `exceptionally`; than that stage does not complete _normally_. As such `thenAcceptAsync` will not be executed, as it's first sentence in the documentation says. So, "rethrow because we want to interrupt the subsequent logic" sort of makes me confused on what you want to achieve

Comment: Inside the `exceptionally` block, it expects a *return value* and if you return something then the `thenAcceptAsync` block will execute. We have to throw the incoming exception `ex` that arrives in the `exceptionally` block in order to jump over the `thenAcceptAsync`.